# How do I save a custom c++ class object to NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I want to add a C++ Class object into `NSUserDefaults`. If I add it directly, it crashes. 
How do I add c++ Class object to NSUserDefaults?

Answer (score 3):

`NSUserDefaults` supports **some** `NSObject`-based classes to be encoded out of the box. Proper way to save custom `NSObject` classes into `NSUserDefaults` instance is to encode them into `NSData` and save it.

In your case, since you have a C++ class, you could either wrap it's data to an `NSObject` (`NSDictionary` maybe) or implement a class <-> string serialisation and deserialisation, saving a string object into the `NSUserDefaults` instance.